# Are the following two statements semantically same?

Tags: c++, initialization, semantics

Are the following two statements semantically same?

#1 `person p("Rahul", 20);`

#2 `person const &p = person("Rahul", 20);`

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I meant to ask whether the following two are semantically same:

#1 `person const p("Rahul", 20);`

#2 `person const &p = person("Rahul", 20);`

Comment: @Space_Cowboy: It's a valid C++98.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not. However, the difference are affected only by the fact that the second case needs a copy constructor to be accessible in C++03 (even if the copy constructor call is not actually done)

```
// works with #1 fails with #2
struct f1 { f1(string, int); private: f1(f1 const&); };
```

Answer (score 5):

No they are not. The way that p behaves in each case is different. For example, in the latter case, you could not say:

```
p.rename( "fred" );
```

assuming person had a rename() method.

Of course, if your first instance had been:

```
const person p("Rahul", 20);
```

the two would have been much more similar. I hope you are not intending  using references for all your "variables" :-)

Comment: So they are similar, not same?

Comment: @Rahul With the const version, I can't think of a way of telling them apart, but I'm sure someone else will come up with something.

Comment: You can define a reference to (what appears to be) a temporary, and that temporary sticks around? I didn't know that.

Comment: @Ari Yes you can, otherwise reference function parameters that refer to temps wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm not talking about creating the reference, I was surprised about the temporary surviving after the statement in which it is created.  When calling a function with references to temps, the expression's evaluation ends after the function returns.

Comment: Temporaries can be bound to const references and persist for the lifetime of the reference, but function arguments are one of the exceptions - see *§12.2/5* for details.